# Ms Excel - Randomly assign up to 3 Names, at least 1, as equally as possible to each Job

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[I can't post Image yet lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT9Yy.png)

As you can see on the picture above there are 10 jobs and 4 persons working on it. I'm trying to assign up to 3 persons (at least one) to each Job randomly, but with these constraints:

1. Each person must have at least one Job,
2. Each Job must have unique Persons (obviously),
3. Jobs should be distributed as equally as possible to all Persons.

Is this possible to achieve with only formulas?

Comment: You really don't want random assignment, you need to "systematically" assign. In order to do that you need to come up with your process to assign. In the simpliest case just start with one person and go down your list and then restart at the top until all your your jobs are assigned. Then you can figure out how to layer in a second person, and third person. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example sheet I worked out that essentially fits the criterion you prescribed:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to restructure your job table, this should basically fit your criteria. It's not random at all but I don't see a reason it should be.

**table named "jobs"**

| Jobs | Person |
| --- | --- |
| Job 1 | Person 3 |
| Job 2 | Person 4 |
| Job 3 | Person 1 |
| Job 4 | Person 2 |
| Job 5 | Person 3 |
| Job 6 | Person 4 |
| Job 7 | Person 1 |
| Job 8 | Person 2 |
| Job 9 | Person 3 |
| Job 10 | Person 4 |

**table named "people"**

| Person Names |
| --- |
| Person 1 |
| Person 2 |
| Person 3 |
| Person 4 |

**formula for the "Person" column in the "jobs" table**

```
=INDEX(people[Person Names],MOD(ROW(),COUNTA(people[Person Names]))+1,1)
```